# CheckedListBox WinForms Binding

Tags: winforms, binding, checkedlistbox

How can I bind my object collection to CheckedListBox items with **IsChecked** property?

Here is my objects:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}
}

public class EditorModel
{
    public BindingList<Person> People {get;set;}
}
```

These objects both implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** also.

I can do binding like this:

```
checkedListBox.DataSource = editorViewModel.People;
checkedListBox.ValueMember = "Id";
checkedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

How can I bind the third property **IsChecked**? I tried to google it, but I haven't found any solution.

Comment: I don't think the `IsChecked` member of your `Person` class is named very well. `Id` and `Name` make sense on their own, but `IsChecked`, without any further information, doesn't make sense without the context of the `CheckedListBox`. Also, I don't think you can bind it directly considering the checked state seems to be mainly intended for creating a subset of items in the list to iterate over, going by the `CheckedItemsCollection` stuff here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx.

Comment: (You could still utilize [the `ItemCheck` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) to set the property manually, though.)

Comment: It makes sense in my case. I store this records in database and I don't want to manually set this property in code behind before object saving. If it's impossible I will do this via DataGridView control. Thanks.

Comment: Having it stored in a database is even more reason to not use an uninformative property name like `IsChecked`. What does it mean for a `Person` to be "checked"? But regardless of that, it does seem that `CheckedListBox` isn't intended for what you want, unless you could use the `DataBindings` property to bind the collective `IsChecked` properties of your `Person` objects to the `CheckedItems` property of the `CheckedListBox`. I don't have enough experience with data bindings in the .NET framework to know if that would work or not.

Comment: `IsChecked` was just for example. I know that it is a bad name. Should be something like `IsActive` or anything else. Anyway using DataGridView is a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem**

All the solutions in binding a datasource to a CheckedListBox aren't very elegant.

**Solution**

Use a DataGridView with a Checkbox column instead.